# OS X - Cannot find ssl headers

Tags: macos, ssl

We have few OS X build agents, and during NRPE installation - on one of them I got an error:

```
bash-3.2# ./configure --enable-command-args
...
checking for SSL headers... configure: error: Cannot find ssl headers
```

As Linux user - i'd say I need to install something like `yum install openssl-dev` - but what is solution on OS X?

```
bash-3.2# system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType

Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: OS X 10.10.5 (14F1021)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 14.5.0
      Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
```

I have tried to search something similar to `openssl-dev` or `libssl-dev` with `brew search /ssl*/` but got nothing related to `develop` - only exactly `openssl` package installed.

Comment: `brew install openssl` is the homebrew instruction to install it. but if `brew search '/ssl*/'` didn't display openssl and a whole load of other packages for you (not the quotes to prevent the shell from interpreting it), then you may have an issue with your homebrew install, so you could try the `brew doctor`

Comment: @Petesh Thanks. I have been updated my Q - I have `openssl` installed, but nothing about headers for it.

Comment: homebrew openssl doesn't link into the `/usr/local/include` by default. if you use `--with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl` as part of the configure line it should work, or set some variables (look at the output of `brew info openssl`

Comment: @Petesh Thanks. I found solution. It's "Spike Solition" - but it works. In `configure` script I found which file it's trying to find: `if test -f "$dir/include/openssl/ssl.h"; then`; then I found where it's located on my other OSX host; and have copied directory `/opt/local/include/openssl/` from working host in to `/usr/local/openssl` on the problematic host - and it's works :-)